# How to sort a table column by clicking icons

Tags: reactjs, sorting

Please have a look on a very simple React table app in [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-moore-l843fj?file=/src/App.jsx).
I'd like sort the Product column by clicking on the red icons.
Actualty clicking on red icon a message is displayed in the console.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thans in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own sort function? Also I recommend using a toggle of some sort instead of having directed ascending/descending arrows (though you can show them to notate direction)... For an ID you can have it sort both by id (as a number) and for Price you can do the same... For the Product title you will want to sort by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment I left you, having specific arrows to click on is not a good idea (though you can show an arrow to indicate what direction it is currently being sorted by).

First you will want to have your products array stored in a react hook (useState). You can do that by modifying from:
`const products = [{...},{...},...];` to
`const [products, setProducts] = useState([{...},{...},...]);`
You can learn about hooks [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Now you will need to modify the state of the products when sorting for react to know when your state has been updated and to re-render your state. So your products would look something like this, and the two functions as follows... ->

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      product: "Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite 8.7",
      price: 119.35
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      product: "Motorola Moto G Stylus 5G",
      price: 149.99
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      product: "OnePlus Nord N30 5G",
      price: 299.59
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      product: "TCL 40XL 2023",
      price: 169.99
    }
  ]);

  const sortAscending = () => {
    const temp = [...products];
    temp.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.product.localeCompare(b.product);
    });
    setProducts(temp);
  };
  const sortDescending = () => {
    const temp = [...products];
    temp.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.product.localeCompare(a.product);
    });
    setProducts(temp);
  };
```

If you notice in each sorting function, I'm creating a copy of the products array, sorting that copy, then updating the state of products with that copy... This is super important because if you only update the products reference or create a variable reference of products and update that, react will not detect the change and no update will happen... You can see this array being copied (instead of referenced when I call 
`const temp = [...products];` If you don't know yet, the `...` is the spread operator you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) 
 To see your same example with this update you can view that in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/sortable-table-forked-5547x9?file=/src/App.jsx) CodeSandBox

Comment: The key point in your valuable answer was to *create a copy* of the products array.
[SOLVED]